# Flask-Login raises TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I just write a flask login demo.

```
@app.route('/reg/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reg():
    username = request.form.get('username').strip()
    password = request.form.get('password').strip()
    if (username == '' or password == ''):
        return redirect_with_msg('/regloginpage/', u'用户名或密码不能为空', category='reglogin')

    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
    if (user != None):
        return redirect_with_msg('/regloginpage/', u'用户名已存在', category='reglogin')

    salt = '.'.join(random.sample('0123456789abcdfeghijklmnABCDEFG', 10))
    m = hashlib.md5()
    str1 = (password + salt).encode('utf-8')
    m.update(str1)
    password = m.hexdigest()
    user = User(username, password, salt)
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    login_user(user)
    return redirect('/')
```

And Traceback like this:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/apple/PycharmProjects/pinstagram/pinstagram/views.py", line 94, in login
login_user(user)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 140, in login_user
user_id = getattr(user, current_app.login_manager.id_attribute)()
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

It makes me upset, someone can save me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the error message shows that the error is occurring on line 140 of utils.py. This is probably because you have

```
user_id = getattr(user, current_app.login_manager.id_attribute)()
```

The () on the end is making your program try to call the return value of getattr as a function, when it is an int. Remove the () and it should work.

Comment: Jesus!!!! I find the traceback ,but the utils.py is not mine, it's made by flask_login . So I don't know how to solve it.And your answer gives me the solution. Thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this same issue with flask-login and landed on this question. While @Sweater-Baron's answer hints at the issue, here's the direct fix in your `User` class since it doesn't make sense to edit `Flask-Login`. The method `get_id()` should not be declared as a property:

```
@property
def get_id(self):
    return self.uid
```

unlike `is_authenticated()`, `is_active()` and `is_anonymous()`.

```
def get_id(self):
    return self.uid
```

From the [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#your-user-class) documentation:

> **get_id()**
>
> This **method** must return a unicode that uniquely identifies this user, and
>   can be used to load the user from the user_loader callback.

[emphasis is mine]

Comment: This should be the true answer, It is not good to edit the dependency source code, All edits will be overwritten by pip update. and the code will not work for other users as they recieve fresh copy of the depndency.